# Convert file extension to lowercase on upload wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a problem while uploading images to wagtail admin panel. The issue is that if i upload a file with a capitalized extension like .JPG the file brakes. Is there a way of converting the format to lowercase on upload?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I missed out on bunch of important details, I thought this can be fixed easily now i think that might not be the case.

There is no error on the admin side, the file gets uploaded fine.
I'm using Wagtail with graphene-django to create an API and Next.js on the frontend. So the image brakes only on the frontend if the extension is capitalized.

I'm using a standard Wagtail page model and standard Image Field

```py
class BlogPage(HeadlessPreviewMixin, Page):
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+"
    )
```

Comment: Hey, what kind of error are you getting when uploading the file (both on the admin and on your server), it seems odd that an uppercase extension would break. What operating system is the Wagtail server running on? [edit] Also - do you have a custom Image model and if so can you put the model's code in the question.

Comment: @LBBenJohnston I edited the question with more insight, hope this helps you to help me :)